# How to run java function for only 30 minutes

Tags: java, function, time, timer

I need to create a java function that will only run for 30 minutes, and at the end of the 30 minutes it executes something. But it should also be able to self terminate before the given time if the right conditions are met. I don't want the function to be sleeping as it should be collecting data, so no sleeping threads.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: [Timer.schedule( TimerTask, long )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29)

```
public void someFunctino() {
    // set the timeout    
    // this will stop this function in 30 minutes
    long in30Minutes = 30 * 60 * 1000;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
          public void run() {
               if( conditionsAreMet() ) { 
                   System.exit(0);
                }
           }
     },  in30Minutes );

     // do the work... 
      .... work for n time, it would be stoped in 30 minutes at most
      ... code code code
}
```

Comment: Thats way better, it wont run thousand times :D

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method schedule(TimerTask, long) from the type Timer

Comment: wouldn't this just run a task 30 minutes later... rather than run it "for" 30 minutes...

Comment: The `System#exit()` will however kill the entire JVM. Not sure if this is what OP had in mind.

Comment: @BaluC indeed, a more complex mechanism is needed, but I hope this would give him a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Get the start time with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, calculate the time when to stop and check the current time every now and then while you're collecting the data you want to collect. Another way would be to decouple the timer and the data collecting, so that each of them could run in their own threads.

For a more specific answer, it would be helpful if you would tell *what* data you are collecting and *how* you are collecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long maxDurationInMilliseconds = 30 * 60 * 1000;

while (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + maxDurationInMilliseconds) {
    // carry on running - 30 minutes hasn't elapsed yet

    if (someOtherConditionIsMet) {
        // stop running early
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. It can be a good idea to throw in a short Thread.sleep() in every iteration as well unless you want to eat 100% of a CPU

Comment: Minor suggestion: assign `startTime + maxDurationInMilliseconds` to a variable and use that variable in the loop condition. That way the addition won't be performed 1800000 times :)

Comment: @Anita: I would imagine the VM would hoist that calculation out of the condition and calculate it just once. After all, `startTime` and `maxDurationInMilliseconds` are local to the running thread.

Comment: @mikera: depends on the work that's being done by the method. It might involve a lot of I/O, or might be issuing requests and waiting for a reponse. The question was a bit vague. Of course if the method is simply waiting for (up to) 30 minutes, then yes, it should sleep for a while in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The modern `java.util.concurrent` way would be using [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). There are several `invoke` methods taking a timeout.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new Task()), 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

where `Task` look like this:

```
public class Task implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() {
        // Just a dummy long running task.
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger("0");
        for (long l = 0; l < Long.MAX_VALUE; l++) {
            i.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(l)));

            // You need to check this regularly..
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Task interrupted!");
                break; // ..and stop the task whenever Thread is interrupted.
            }
        }
        return null; // Or whatever you'd like to use as return value.
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Lesson: Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)