# Java: Thread/task expiration after specified milliseconds

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, timertask

In Java is there a sane way to have a thread/task run continuously and then end after a specified run time (preferably without using several timers)?

For instance, if I have a [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html), there doesn't seem to be a way to schedule that task to end after a certain number of milliseconds or at a specific time with the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class.

Sure, I can schedule a task to [*repeat*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) after a number of milliseconds, but what if I want it to end after one iteration? I have to run another timer within this scheduled task? I'm hoping for a more elegant answer than that.

The answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826042/how-to-run-java-function-for-only-30-minutes) could work, but it is definitely not what I had in mind.

**Essentially**, I'm looking for something similar to the [AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx) property on C#'s `System.Timers.Timer` class

Comment: In your `run` method, keep track of the time the method was started and a loop until the desired "time out" is reached...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `ExecutorService`, grab the `Future` you get and `.cancel()` it after the time you want:

```
final Future<Whatever> f = executor.submit(...);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(xxx);
f.cancel(true);
```

Or you can have two services: one which executes, another which uses a `ScheduledExecutorService` for the cancellation.

NOTE: `TimerTask` depends on the system time, use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead.

Comment: Setting this as the answer since it meets my criteria. I'll let you know how it works out for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create another thread and have it time it for when it wants the other thread to stop:

```
class ThreadTimer implements Runnable {
    public void run()
    {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        MainThread.stopThread();
    }
}


class MainThread implements Runnable {
    public boolean running = true;
    public void run()
    {
        // thread running code

        if(!running)
            return;
    }
    public static void stopThread()
    {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Where `3000` is the amount of time in milliseconds from when you want the thread to stop.

Since `Thread.stop()` is deprecated in Java, the next best way is to only execute the thread if a boolean is set to true.  When you call to stop the thread, you're setting that boolean to false, making the code in the thread not run.

Because the void run() doesn't repeat itself and only executes once, if you set the boolean to false, it simply returns `run()` and halts the thread's execution.

Answer (score 0):

If your task is running in a loop, you can check the current time on each iteration, and terminate the loop if enough time has passed.

Or, if your task involves sleeps, you can set a timer on another thread to call `Thread.interrupt` on the task.

The only other option would be to set a timer on another thread to call `Thread.stop`. However, `Thread.stop` [has been deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), and there's no safe way to stop a general thread in Java.